# Data connection problem with my galaxy s3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-connection

Hi I have a peculiar data connection problem with my Samsung Galaxy S3.

Cellular connections work fine at first however when the mobile loses signal and then reconnects after sometime, the data connection doesn't start again automatically (even though mobile data is enabled in settings)

The only way I can turn data back on is by toggling airplane mode.

This doesnot happen everytime the mobile loses signal, perhaps one in three times.

Has anyone experienced this and are there any fixes?

Comment: Which company is your number from? Is it a virtual company (without infrastructure)?

Comment: I have the same problem. I toggle the Data Network mode to restart the connection. No idea why this occurs though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after installing custom rom (ICS for Desire), solved it by installing [Data Connection Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gargamel.data.connection.fix) from Google Play. It now works perfectly.