# Galaxy SIII has a weak data connection

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-connection

I've noticed that my Galaxy SIII has a very weak data connection at times. This occurs even when people around me with the same phone and carrier (T-Mobile) have perfectly adequate connections.

Are there settings somewhere I'm missing? I've looked at the app mentioned in [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37731/data-connection-problem-with-my-galaxy-s3), but would prefer not to install another app if this can be fixed with configuration changes.

Comment: Two things I can think of as possibly useful from a troubleshooting perspective: 1) Do you (you and the other people) have the same type of plan? Specifically, are you on a prepaid plan or anything, and are they on postpaid? That could potentially affect your service if the tower is congested. 2) Have you tried swapping SIMs with someone nearby? That could help narrow down if it's some kind of account/SIM issue or a phone issue.

Comment: I'm on a regular plan (not prepaid) with unlimited data. Have not tried swapping SIMs. Will see if I can find anyone willing to try it.

Answer (score -2):

Look for the signal indicator in between  clock and battery bar. If the signal indicator is full, then voila! You should be able to get the fast data connection.

Comment: Presumably the OP already realizes this, based on the question being how to fix it, not how to check it.

Comment: As @eldarerathis clarified, I'm trying to find a way to boost the signal, not determine what the signal strength is.